# Multi Table SQL dilemma

Tags: sql, t-sql

Need help with a query.

I have these 2 tables:

- Hist: SOnum, Date, Dept
- SOitem: SOnum, Date

I want to COUNT Hist.Date > SOitem.Date Where Hist.Date is between ThisDate and ThatDate and Hist.Dept is 'SHIP' or 'STOCK'

Note: There may be multiple records in table SOitem with the same date and SONum

This is what I have so far but it doesn't return the correct value.

```
SELECT COUNT [SOItemHist].[Dt])
FROM [SOItemHist]
LEFT JOIN [SOItem] ON [SOItemHist].[SONum] = [SOItem].[SONum]
WHERE ([SOItemHist].[Dt] > [SOItem].[ReqDt])
  AND ([SOItemHist].[Dt] BETWEEN '2021-05-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-05-18 00:00:00')
  AND ([SOItemHist].[DeptNum] = 'SHIP' OR [SOItemHist].[DeptNum] = 'STOCK')
```

Comment: It looks good to me based on the logic you shared. Can you share some sample data and your desired results?

Comment: Your need parentheses or to use `in`.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Result should be should be 400+ but getting a result of 3800+. The query works as is.

Comment: Maybe you want an INNER JOIN instead?  Otherwise you're getting all the records from SOItemHist and not just the ones with corresponding records in SOItem.

Comment: Duston, I've tried that. I've tried every join there is. For some odd reason the output is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Understanding the main table must be SoItem and the history records are there in SoItemHist table which may have 1:N relationship between tables. In other words SoItemHist can have multiple records for SoItem. Inner join should work. and will return  exact matching records count.  If you use left outer join you will get all the records in SoItem with matching records from HIST and for those not match will return null.

```
SELECT COUNT ([SOItemHist].[Dt])
FROM [SOItem] 
   INNER JOIN [SOItemHist] ON  [SOItemHist].[SONum] = [SOItem].[SONum]
WHERE [SOItemHist].[Dt] > [SOItem].[ReqDt]
     AND [SOItemHist].[Dt] BETWEEN '2021-05-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-05-18 00:00:00'
     AND [SOItemHist].[DeptNum] in ( 'SHIP' , 'STOCK')
```